# String array and string

Tags: java, android, string, split, arrays

i'm working on a program for my class but now i have a problem with spliting string and substrings. I have saved data from different classes in a string with a delimiter for later a later split(/). This part works fine and i get all the strings as i should saved in a new String array.

Later i tried to toast them in a for loop (String word: String array) and everything seemed fine. But i have a problem with cutting the substring from word. I would like to get the number (between '-' and 'k') but it always throws a String out of index error and i don't know why. When i tried to toast the position of the strings where i would like to take the substring, it shows them fine but when i try to substring with them it throws an error again.

**The Error**

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.uiuracun/com.example.uiuracun.Bill}:
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=29; regionStart=22;
>   regionLength=-18"

**The Code**

```
package com.example.uiuracun;

import android.R.anim;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Bill extends ListActivity {

    // Removed extra code

    private void split(String[] string) {
        for (String word:string){
            word.trim();
            int start = 0;
            int end = 0;
            start = word.indexOf('-');
            end = word.indexOf('k');
            String c = word.substring(start, end);


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you give an input-output sample?

Comment: And what is look like your string containing `-` `k` you can make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) you post code that is not necessary, your problem it seems to be in your method `split` ,much noise there.

Comment: start should be incremented by one and end should be decremented by one

Comment: @AniruddhaSarkar, you are half correct. start should be incremented but the endIndex is exclusive (so it is fine). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message includes `length=29; regionStart=22; regionLength=-18` note the length is negative.

This leads me to believe that the `k` character appears before the `-` character.  Since your code assume `-` always comes first, you get an `end` less than `start`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some information to help you with that exception.

From the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex
>   is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is
>   larger than endIndex.

### UPDATE

I think you should try this:

```
start = word.indexOf('-');

// tell it to start looking for the 'k' starting from the index
// of the '-' that was found.
end = word.indexOf('k', start);

String c = word.substring(start, end);
```

Comment: Yeah i figured it out... Thanks anyway i really appreciate it